# Shortcuts App (iOS 13.1.1): How can I realize a text output in a bigger font size, a specific color, font-weight, ...?

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

I have a shortcut which results in a text output.

It is shown to the user by the action "Overview".
The font size is the standard size of the iOS.

My question:
How can I realize an output in a bigger font size, color, font-weight, ...?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution on my own.

The steps are:

1. Action "Text": Insert the code of a complete HTML web page
2. Action "Create formatted text from HTML"
3. Action "Overview": Show the variable "Formatted text to HTML"

The names of the action may vary, because I use an iOS in german language and do not know the exact names of actions in english.

Hint: The content, which you write into the element "title" will be shown as the title of the window "overview".

If you like to test the shortcut:
https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/4ecffecad4dd42ccac909a15b3a08fd8

Comment: This needs an unlocked device to display the output though.

Comment: If I "Make rich text from <Contents of URL>" and then display `<h1>contnet</h1>, it still ends up being the same text size. Are you diong anything else to display it at a higher text size?